# How to check email stored with password_hash doesn't already exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I'm building a small web application where I ask for people's email addresses and subsequently store them in a MySQL database.  To store them I use the `password_hash` function in PHP.  (This function seems to be used primarily for passwords, though I thought it might be suitable for storing email addresses securely.  If it isn't suitable for some reason, please let me know, and perhaps suggest what I should use instead.)

The trouble I'm having is, when someone signs up and gets their email address stored, I'm not sure if there would be any way to check that the email doesn't already exist in the database, since, as I understand it, subsequent uses of `password_hash` result in new hashes, leaving no way to check?

Also, I'd like to know the best format for the field in a database table for the email column - text? varchar 255?.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. hasing emails is unusual. 2. hashing a string again leads to the same hash if you use the same or no salt.

Comment: pointles. hashing is a one-way function. you cannot "decrypt" the hash to get the email address back out. you can only do email->hash and then compare hashes. hash->email is essentially impossible. Therefore while you may be storing the email "securely", you can't actually use it because the hashing destroyed the address text. and to compare plaintext against a stored hash, you use `password_verify()` anyways, not password_hash again.

Comment: Oh - perhaps I needn't convert them?  I just wanted their emails to be secure.

Comment: Define "secure" first. "Secure" against what exactly?

Comment: OK thank you.  I won't bother encrypting them.

Comment: Note. Hashing isn't encryption.

Comment: You are going to have a heckuva time when it comes to matching / retrieving email addresses. Don't do this unless you don't have to.

Comment: @Fred-ii- s/this unless/this if/ ;)

Comment: @JonStirling I had thought of doing something like that a few months ago, until a friend of mine quickly shot down that idea, in telling me about the pros and **cons** with that. Encryption would work, but hashing will be a much bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of questions here:

**What is the best way to store e-mails in a database?**

The standard for e-mail restricts e-mail addresses to be no longer than 255 characters so VARCHAR(255) is the right choice unless you happen to know that your users will always be smaller. An example would be if you were at a university and knew that no user name is greater than 8 characters and the are all in the format of xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyy.zzzzz.edu. Unless you're doing something like that, stick to VARCHAR(255).

**How can we securely store e-mail addresses?**

A password hash is a one-way function. Once you have a hashed value, you can confirm that a value matches it but you cannot go from the hashed value back to the original value. If you are only concerned with checking to see if the e-mail address was entered before, then you can use the password function or another hash function.

If you ever need to use the e-mail address, you won't be able to get the original from the hashed value. If you want to do that, you need to use some kind of reversible encryption.

If you take a look here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

You can find a good example of reversible encryption. You would essentially do the following:

```
function store_email($user_id, $key){
    $email = get_email($_POST);
    if !(validate_email($email)){
        report_error();
    } else {
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $encrypted_email = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $email, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        store_email($user_id, $encrypted_email);
    }
}

function decode_email($email_field, $key){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = substr($email_field, 0, $iv_size);
    $email_enc = substr($email_field, $iv);
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $email_enc, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}
```

Comment: Why is specifically 255 the right number for varchar...?

Comment: 255 was the largest size for a varchar in older versions of MySQL. According to the [standard](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696&eid=1690), the maximum length for an e-mail address is 254 bytes. My memory was 255 bytes so I suppose you can get away with VARCHAR(254)